# How to solve "Build Failed" error in Java Code runner in VS Code

Tags: java

```
    package Java.School;

public class Compound_Interest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double principal = 100;
        System.out.println("The principal is " + principal);
        double rate = 8;
        System.out.println("The rate of interest p.a. is " + rate + "%");
        double time = 2;
        System.out.println("The time for which the principal has been deposited is " + time + " years");
        double CI = principal*Math.pow(1 + rate/100, time);
        System.out.println("The compound interest received is " + CI);
    }
}
```

So this is my code. But when I am running it, I am getting an error as "Build failed".
On clicking on fix, I get those options of clearing caches and all but they don't work.
On clicking on Proceed, I get another error -

"Error: Could not find or load main class Java.School.Compound_Interest
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Java.School.Compound_Interest"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way that you try to execute this program.
The compiler is trying to find the path-package `Java/School` and inside it the class `Compound_Interest`.

So if you want to run only the file you could remove `package Java.School;` and then run it with:

1. `javac Compound_Interest.java`
2. `java Compound_Interest`

*Also while we are on this topic you should check out how to run java as a project.*

I hope I helped.

Comment: I am grateful of your help but this made no difference to the code. I am still getting the same error. The editor was working perfectly even though I was using "package Java.School" for the past few days. But when I installed the python extensions required for my school project, everything messed up. So, is the python extensions the root cause for the malfunction?

Comment: I don't think that python is the problem. Can you share your project structure and if you are using Intellij the run configuration?

Comment: I reinstalled my OS (windows 10) today as I was even facing issues with C++ and bluetooth headset connectivity. Surprisingly, after the reinstallation, Java in VS Code started working. So, is this a problem with my OS or some bugs due to some other programs? I had reinstalled my OS twice beforehand and the problem was temporarily solved. After a few days, it used to show the "Build failed" error.

No, I am not using Intellij. And by project structure, do you mean the folders and repositories?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your package being camel case is the problem.  Java.School vs java.school

I also think this is OS dependent since Java != java in some OSes (Linux), but is OK in others (Windows).  It wouldn't surprise me if the IDE is creating java/school as the directory which works until the IDE reboots and/or the OS reboots.

Try changing the package name to all lower case.

Comment: I tried switching to lower case "java.School" and also "java.school" (though my folder name is "School"). But  sadly, it did not work ! I am using windows so Java and java is same here ig. VS Code is quite reliable and my teacher uses vs code too but she never faced a problem like I do. (I asked her to try  solving my problem and she  was unable to do so. So, I reached out to this forum)